# Recycleview item is not visible after undo

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, undo

I am a newbie in android programming, in my application, I use a recycleview to show the content of a SQLite database, I am reading the database into an Arraylist, which I show in the recycleview. I have successfully implemented swipe left (delete item) and right (edit item) function.
I have a problem during the left swipe, means with the delete function, I have implemented an undo function:

```
    void restoreItem( SequenceItem sequenceItem, int position) {
    sequenceItemList.add(position, sequenceItem);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
    }
```

(SequenceItem is my custom item class, and sequenceItemList is my arraylist)

This function works well if I delete a list item between the first or the last item and undo them. If I delete the first or the last item in the recycleview after the undo I see a blank space at that position, the list item layout is absolutely not visible, it is just white.
Then I have added a "recycleview.scrollToPosition" after I call the restore method:

```
    recycleAdapter.restoreItem(deletedItem, deletedIndex);
    recyclerView.scrollToPosition(deletedIndex);
```

After this change, if I delete the first item from the recycleview than I click on undo, the previously deleted item is restored correctly, but if I delete the last item from the recycleview and click on undo, I still see a blank (white) item.

Could please help me what could be the problem?
If you need further details, I can post more code or tell more about the application.

EDITED on 06.10.2018
I have attached the RecyclerItemTouchHelper class because, in my opinion, this is causing the issue:

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(Context mContext, int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
        this.listener = listener;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    //This is not used
    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder1) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        if (listener != null) {
            listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        View list_foreground = ((RecycleAdapter.mViewHolder)viewHolder).list_foreground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(list_foreground);
    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            View list_foreground = ((RecycleAdapter.mViewHolder)viewHolder).list_foreground;
            getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(list_foreground);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {

        float mdX = dX / 1;

        if(actionState == ItemTouchHelper.ACTION_STATE_SWIPE){

            Bitmap icon;
            Paint p = new Paint();

            Resources resources = mContext.getResources();

            View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
            float height = (float) itemView.getBottom() - (float) itemView.getTop();
            float width = height / 3;

            if(dX > 0){ //Swipe right
                p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#D32F2F"));
                RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() , (float) itemView.getTop(), mdX, (float) itemView.getBottom());
                c.drawRect(background,p);
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_delete_white);
                RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getLeft() + width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getLeft()+ 2*width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
            } else { //Swipe left
                p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#388E3C"));
                RectF background = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() + mdX, (float) itemView.getTop(), (float) itemView.getRight(), (float) itemView.getBottom());
                c.drawRect(background,p);
                icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.ic_edit_white);
                RectF icon_dest = new RectF((float) itemView.getRight() - 2*width ,(float) itemView.getTop() + width,(float) itemView.getRight() - width,(float)itemView.getBottom() - width);
                c.drawBitmap(icon,null,icon_dest,p);
            }
        }
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, mdX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        View list_foreground = ((RecycleAdapter.mViewHolder)viewHolder).list_foreground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, list_foreground, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }
}
```

And here is the activity implementation of the swipe:

```
    @Override
public void onSwiped(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, final int position) {
    //Swipe LEFT to DELETE
    if (direction == ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootLayout, "Phase " + (position + 1) + " is removed!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

        //Backup of removed item dor UNDO purpose
        final SequenceItem deletedItem = sequenceItemList.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
        final int deletedIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

        //Remove the item from recyclerview
        recycleAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

        snackbar.setAction(R.string.undo, new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Restore deleted item
                recycleAdapter.restoreItem(deletedItem, deletedIndex);
                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(deletedIndex);

            }
        }).addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int dismissType) {
                super.onDismissed(snackbar, dismissType);

                if (dismissType != DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION) {
                    //Delete the item from the database
                    databaseHelper.removePhase(deletedItem);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.phase_successfully_deleted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.warningColor));
        snackbar.show();
    }
    //Swipe RIGHT to EDIT
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddPhaseActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("dbPosition", (long) viewHolder.itemView.getTag());
        intent.putExtra("rvPosition", position);
        recycleAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks strange.
First of all you dont need call both at the same time.

notifyItemInserted(position); 
and
notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());

Can you try call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and tell if something change?

Comment: First of all some additional details, every item in the recycleview has a visible number which shows the position from top. And if I remove the notifyItemInserted(position); (but notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount()); is still there) then the recyclerview absolutely not restored after undo (of course if I start a new activity and goes back I see the correct recycleview) then if use only notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount()); then item position number is not updated but the items are restored except the last one in the list.

Comment: If I use only notifyDataSetChanged(); then the deleted item is restored except the last one in the list, and in case of the usage of only notifyDataSetChanged(); the restored item has no animation.

Comment: May be one more thing, I swipe the items right I draw a red background and draw a delete icon in the recycleviewItemTouchHelper - onChildDraw method. So may be this causing the problem that I see a white item instead of the correct listitem layout.

Comment: Look at this article. https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/
It explains main positions, may be you missed something.
It is difficult to solve you problem with part of code you posted, because it looks ok.

Comment: Thanks, exactly this guide what I have followed to implement the "delete, undo". The only difference is that I am drawing the delete background and icon, in the guide he is implemented a foreground view (item view) and background view (delete view) in the frame layout. I can post more details just give me some hint which part would be useful. (Unfortunately my code is not available in github.) When I first implemented the delete, undo feature I exactly did what he wrote, and it was working, but I have changed it to draw the background because I need an edit background sweep as well.

Comment: Maybe one behavior what I have just recognized, e.g. I have three items in the list if I swipe the last (3.) item to right to delete it, it disappears and when I click on undo, nothing happens, then when I swipe right (to delete) the last visible item (2.) (the last item (3.) is not visible after undo) then after the swipe of the second item is done, the third item is automatically starting to swipe from right to left to its position. Then I click on the snackbar undo which was shown after the second item was swiped to delete then all my three items are visible in the recyclerview.

Comment: Do you notify adapter with `notifyItemRemoved(position)` after removing item?

Or does your item remain swiped in the RecyclerView?

Comment: Yes, the removeItem method in the recyclerview adapter has notifyItemRemoved and notifyItemRangeChanged.

Comment: I'm very interested what is wrong with your items behaviour.
Can you share broken part ( via email or private bitbucket repository), so I can look at it and check.

Comment: I have removed the drawing on canvas in case of item swiped left or right. I have added two additional background views (one for delete and one for edit), like in the guide what you also shared. In that case, the swipe delete/edit function is working well. So I think the swipe drawing on canvas implementation has some failure. Of course, I can share more details, I would prefer the email. Thanks to your help.

Comment: ok, write me your email, I will write you a message

Comment: I did not find the way how I can get in contact with you (Viktor Vasyliev), so I have edited the original post, with the item touch helper and with the activity implementation.

Comment: Added answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok. 
The only possible place for that strange perfomance is function below.

`@Override 
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
 View list_foreground = ((RecycleAdapter.mViewHolder)viewHolder).list_foreground; getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(list_foreground);
}`

You clear wrong view. Try to clear root view of your item, like

`@Override 
public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
View itemView= ((RecycleAdapter.mViewHolder)viewHolder).itemView; getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(itemView);
}`

OR

change your 
    `public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive)` method.

put

`View list_foreground = ((RecycleAdapter.mViewHolder)viewHolder).list_foreground;
getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, list_foreground, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);`

instead of

`super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, mdX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);`

It will fix your problem.

EXPLANATION:

The source of problem is that `onChildDraw` method calls

`super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, mdX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);`

And it calls 
`onDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView, View view,
                float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive)`
     function inside passing `viewHolder.itemView` as argument for `view` and implementing translation to it like

`view.setTranslationX(dX);
  view.setTranslationY(dY);`

But clear view works like

```
    @Override
    public void clearView(View view) {
        view.setTranslationX(0f);
        view.setTranslationY(0f);
    }
```

So in your case functions `onChildDraw` and `clearView` work with different views.

Comment: Thanks your investigation, I will make a try and let you know about the result.